# HTML Image map with overlay/tooltip

Tags: html, tooltip, overlay, imagemap

I had tried use `title` in `HTML image map`.
It works but i would like to have a bigger pop out or overlay.
Anyone has coding example on `tooltip/overlay` on `HTML image map` ?

Comment: Hi. This kind of question is off-topic for SO. Check out the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for information about what is on-topic and how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

**This might be helpful:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        
        <p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>
        
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=18roW6-rCYtpxhRE91wt6YimBJ5k0h7jZ" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
        
        <map name="planetmap">
          <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
          <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
          <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
        </map>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```